# Passing variables values

Tags: javascript

here is the simple script:

```
function parentFunc() {
    var x = 15;
    process(x);
}

parentFunc();

function process(x) {
    alert(x);
}​
```

Now when the page loads, `parentFunc()` is being executed which calls `process()` function along with sending the paramter to it; Is there any way to make it so that when `parentFunc()` is called it just sends the parameters to `process()` function without executing it? I need a solution without global variables.

Comment: What does "ends the parameters to process() function without executing it" mean? Do you want to bind `x` to a certain later for later executing?

Comment: I think this answer might be rude, but: No. There's something wrong with your iteration or your algorithm. Either you got to use globals, or you've to reconsider your idea at this point.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to bind a certain argument to `process` and execute the function later?

You can do this with [`.bind()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It accepts a context and arguments and creates a new function:

```
var process_bound = process.bind(null, x);
// later
process_bound();
```

For an implementation for browsers that don't support `.bind()`, have a look at the MDN documentation (or see Rocket's comment).

---

Here is how you should use it:

```
function process(x) {
    alert(x);
}​

function parentFunc() {
    var x = 15;
    return process.bind(null, x);
}

var process_bound = parentFunc();

// now bind the event handler to the element

var element = document.getElementById('someId');
element.onclick = function() {
    process_bound();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: `.bind` may not work in all browsers, if it doesn't work try this: `var process_bound = function(x){return function(){process(x);}}(x)`.

Comment: @Rocket: Right, the MDN documentation provides an implementation as well.

Comment: I just need to pass the variable 'x' declared in parentFunc() in another function process() and use it further in this function

Comment: @user976813: But that is what you are already doing... I understand your problem then. You do `alert(x);`, instead of that you can do whatever with `x`.

Comment: yes:) here is the case:
function parentFunc() - is being executed on page load and it triggers function process(). So I was wondering if there is any option just to pass the parameter from one function to another without having to call process() function?

Comment: @user976813: Yes... and? What is the problem with that? What are you trying to say with that?

Comment: in my case i want process() to be triggered by onclick event (which i have on a link element in my html) and instead it is being triggered by parentFunc()

Comment: @user976813: But you want `x` to be passed to `process` by `parentFunc`?

Comment: Ok, then you can do it as I said in my answer. You can have `parentFunc` return the bound function and use it in a click event handler. Where is the problem?

Comment: thank you man; finally, this seems to be what i really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure - you can pass a different value to x and create a different frame of reference for each time you call parentscript.

```
function parentscript(x) {
process = function(){
    alert(x)
}
return process
}
f = parentscript(23);
f(); //alerts 23
```