# Access local variable from another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

I want to do the following in my script:

Declare 2 variables in one function and call this function on window load. After that use values of those 2 variables in my other functions. Any option to do this without having to declare those variables outside the function as globals?

Again, it is important that the variables are declared inside a function which will be called on page load.

HTML code:

```
<a href=''onclick='_default();return false;'>Link</a>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function _default() {
    var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;
    _main(x, h);
}
_default();

function _main(x, h) {
    alert(x);
    alert(h);
}
```

You will see that this script executes `_default()` on page load. `_default()` function passes 2 parameters to `_main()` and executes `_main()` function throwing 2 alerts with variables `x` and `h`. But how do I make it so that those 2 alerts are thrown when I click on the link (see html code above)?

Comment: Why are you asking a new question about this? Your previous question is about the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621495/passing-variables-values.  If you don't understand my answer, then ask for clarification but don't ask a new question.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, since it seems you don't know how to bind event handlers with JavaScript (you never answered my last comment). I also recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn the basics about event handling.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem, then it is bacause when default() is called for the first time, the page has not been fully rendered, so 'mydiv' will be null.

If you remove the line that calls _default(), and instead call it from body onload, you should find that it works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function _default() {
            var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
            var h = x.offsetHeight;

            _main(x, h);
        }

        function _main(x, h) {
            alert(x);
            alert(h);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="_default();">
    <a href='' onclick='_default();return false;'>Link</a>
    <div id='mydiv'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work because its executed before the DOM is ready ... change it like so :

```
function _default() {
    var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;
    _main(x, h);
}

function _main(x, h) {
    alert(x);
    alert(h);
}

window.onload = _default;
```

This causes the `_default()` function to be executed when the `load` event is triggered ... [you can read more about the `window.onload` method here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload?action=edit)

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xcPPS/)